# How to write conditional statements in Apache Camel

Tags: if-statement, apache-camel, conditional-statements

I have started working with Apache Camel, and have run into a situation where I need to execute following conditional block.

```
if(Condition A) {
   then Activity A to determine Condition B;
   If(Condition B) {
       Then Activity B
   } else {
       Then Activity C
   }
} else {
  Do nothing and end the route.
}
```

Here is what i have come up with, but it is nothing more than guess. It is not written with proper understanding.

```
...
...
.process(new SomeActivity())
.choice()
   .when(header(ConditionA).isEqualTo(Boolean.TRUE))
      .process(new ActivityToSetConditionB())
   .choice()
      .when(header(ConditionB).isEqualTo(Boolean.TRUE))
         .process(new ActivityRelatedToB())
      .otherwise()
         .process(new ActivityRelatedToC())
   .endChoice()
.end()
```

I have tried to understand from Apache camel documentation and few other sources, but it does not seem very intuitive for a beginner like me. Please help me understand this with some examples.

Comment: Can you post your actual route config?

Comment: I think you guess is good. it is the right way to work with conditional statements in camel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your use of the [Content based router](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/022e1f2693ed753fdec763190370244669466286/core/camel-core-engine/src/main/docs/modules/eips/pages/dynamicRouter-eip.adoc) is the correct way to deal with conditional message routing.

However, if you want to get a better understanding of Camel I highly recommend the book [Camel in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition) (2nd edition). You will find all the important concepts of the framework and lots of examples in the book.

Comment: page not found for first link

Comment: thanks for your comment, link is fixed